# Can I cite a manuscript in term paper

Tags: publications, citations

I am doing a term paper on the subject of minimum spanning trees algorithms,
I need to cite "Shortest connection networks and some generalization" paper for the prim's algorithm made by Prim, after searching I found a manuscript of the paper.
My question is, can I cite the paper? is this allowed in the citing formats?

Comment: If you use the information, you *must* cite the source. End of story. If by manuscript you mean a pre-print, the final peer-reviewed article will carry more weight so you should access the published article if you can.

Comment: (You should cite Jarník's earlier paper describing the same algorithm as well. See also [this PhD thesis](http://mj.ucw.cz/papers/saga/), which includes a detailed literature survey.)

Comment: Like many others you should cite: R. C. Prim, “Shortest connection networks and some generalization,” Bell System Technical Journal, 36: 1389-1401, 1957.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can cite unpublished manuscripts; this is regularly done in academia. However, the important issue is that you must appropriately indicate that it is an unpublished manuscript, and cite (if possible) where the manuscript was found. This will allow for due consideration of the work in context.