# Can I add new coauthor after submitting the paper in arxiv?

Tags: mathematics, ethics, paper-submission, arxiv

At first I suggest readers to look [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/193943/how-to-handle-a-coauthor-who-is-very-late-in-finalizing-a-research-paper). My current question is related to that.

In [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/193943/how-to-handle-a-coauthor-who-is-very-late-in-finalizing-a-research-paper), I said that my coauthor is not replying/submitting the paper in arxiv.

Now the issue is that I have prepared another paper in which I need to cite our joined paper. So unless my coauthor submit that joined paper in arxiv, I can not cite it. (Is there other way to cite a paper, which is neither in a jounal nor in any online database arxiv ?)

Since I am not getting reply from my coauthor, I have the following options:

- I can submit the paper in arxiv without my coauthor's consent but adding their name ?
- I can submit the paper in arxiv without my coauthor's consent but without adding their names ? Would arxiv moderators considers adding a new coauthor without any revision in the content ?

Thanks

Comment: Regarding your parenthetical question, see [How to cite a working paper, preprint, or manuscript?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/116004/17254) for some options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least in math, in the bibliography, you can put anything you like with a note "preprint, in preparation" or "preprint, available upon request" or just "preprint." Sometimes it leads to undesirable results (if the cited work never materializes, but this is, hopefully, not your case). If journal's referee asks you for that preprint, explain the situation and send them what you have, explaining that it should not be shared because of an issue with your collaborator. I had such a situation with my collaborator: It took several years for them to agree to post a joint paper on the arXiv and few more years after that to submit to a journal. In the meantime, I had to apply for jobs and share the preprint with my recommendation letter-writers. Sigh...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Hopefully my coathor replied today. The matter is solved now

Answer (score 7):

I'm not really understanding all the surrounding issues here, but fairly simply:

You should not post to a preprint server or submit to a journal any work unless all the authors have agreed to submit.

You should not post to a preprint server or submit to a journal any work that fails to include an author who should be an author.

Comment: @learner You have a communication problem to resolve with your coauthor. You cannot solve this problem by submitting without their permission or leaving them off. I do not understand why submitting the paper is *their* duty, though, it seems like if you simply ask for their permission to submit then it's far more likely they can simply say "okay", whereas if you insist that *they* submit then you have created a task for them that is not as fun and exciting as their other duties.

Comment: @learner It's not reasonable to expect response to email in one day. Do you see your coauthor in person ever? Do you have a phone number for them?

Comment: @learner Most likely they are simply busy and your project is a very low priority to them. Do you have a local mentor that you interact with more directly?

Comment: @learner A day is a very long time when your schedule is busy. Ask your supervisor for advice.

Comment: +1. I would add: You should not post to a preprint server or submit to a journal any work that includes an author who should not be an author.